# which one of the words is correct to use in my sentence? (field/ industry/ job)

Tags: word-choice

> As a freelance writer, you have to prove them that you are skilled enough ****in**/**at**/**on**** your **field**/ **industry**/ **job**.

Comment: Hi! Please edit your question to explain more about the problem. Pure proofreading questions ("Is this right or wrong") are not on-topic here. Please also clarify the meaning that you want. Many of these are equally right, with slightly different meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these phrases are correct:

> As a freelance writer, you have to prove them that you are skilled enough in your field.

> As a freelance writer, you have to prove them that you are skilled enough atn your job.